# How can I make the scanner search for a token, then return the one after it?

Tags: java, file, search, input, java.util.scanner

I want the strings `inning`, `battingTeam`, `outs`, `balls`, and `strikes` in an `ArrayList<String>`.
In other words, I need the string that immediately follows the tag `@attribute`.  `@relation` and `@data` and anything that follows on that line should not wind up in this ArrayList.

> @relation stats
>
> @attribute inning real
>
> @attribute battingTeam {0,1}
>
> @attribute outs {0,1,2}
>
> @attribute balls {0,1,2,3}
>
> @attribute strikes {0,1,2}
>
> @data
>   1,0,0,0,1,"CX",0,0,"crisc001","R","crisc001","R","wilsc004","L","wilsc004","L","","","","T","F",8,1,no

This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("2013ALL.csv");

    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();


    String line = "";

    while (!line.startsWith("@attribute"));
    {
        line = scanFile.nextLine();
    }

    do
    {
        line = scanFile.nextLine();
        String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
        headers.add(splitLine[1]);
    }
    while (line.startsWith("@attribute"));
    System.out.println(headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("2013ALL.csv"));
    String l = s.nextLine();
    while (s.hasNextLine() && l.startsWith("@")) {
        if (l.startsWith("@attribute")) {
            String[] splitLine = l.split(" ");
            headers.add(splitLine[1]);
        }
        l = s.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(headers);
}
```

This code only adds elements after the `@attribute` tag. Please notice that it doesn't do any error checking, for example checking the `length` of `splitLine` before trying to access the element at index 1.

Comment: This works.  I assume now the scanner is positioned such that I can just read the rest of the file (after the `@data` line) like a normal csv?

Comment: @ReiHinoX After the `while` loop the `Scanner` has gone through the whole file. If you want the `while` to stop right after `@data`, you could add a condition to the loop such as: `while (s.hasNextLine() && l.startsWith("@")) ... ` so the `Scanner` will be positioned at the next line not starting with `@`.  
May I suggest you use a `BufferedReader` for reading through files as it has better performance and allows you to `mark` and `reset` the position. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

Comment: If I add that condition, `l` would not have a value the first time the loop triggered. Therefore the condition `l.startsWith("@")` would automatically be false and the loop would never execute.

Comment: @ReiHinoX I updated the code so you could use the `l.startsWith("@")` condition.